# How to get all the values of a field using entities.Database.SqlQuery?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api

I have a stored procedure that may returns more than one values of a field.

For example:  [image]

I need to create an `API` that will get all the values of the same field.

My controller has the following code:

```
public partial class get_active_call_info_id_Result
    {
        public int call_info_id { get; set; }
    }

public partial class error_message
        {
            public int StatusCode { get; set; }
        }

[BasicAuthentication]
        [Route("getactivecallinfoid")]
        [HttpPost, ActionName("getactivecallinfoid")]
        public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<String> GetACII(String u_id)
        {
            //var data = (dynamic)null;
            using (EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
            {
                String jsonResult = null;
                String jsonResult_log = null;

                entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                var query = entities.Database.SqlQuery<get_active_call_info_id_Result>("exec [dbo].[get_active_call_info_id] @user_id", new SqlParameter("user_id", u_id))
                    .Select(x => new
                    {   
                        x.call_info_id,
                        StatusCode = 1 //Success StatusCode
                    }).ToList();

                bool isEmpty = !query.Any();
                if (isEmpty)
                {
                    error_message error_status = new error_message()
                    {
                        StatusCode = 0
                    };

                    jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error_status);
                  
                }
                else
                {
                    jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query[0]); // <-- using Newtonsoft.Json
                   
                }

                return Json(jsonResult);
            }
        }
```

The result I get calling this API through `POSTMAN` is:

```
"{\"call_info_id\":3,\"StatusCode\":1}"
```

The correct one should be something like:

```
"{\"call_info_id\":3, \"call_info_id\":4,\"StatusCode\":1}"
```

Comment: you are only serialising the first item in the array - rather than query[0] just serialise query and you should end up with something like `"[{\"call_info_id\":3}, {\"call_info_id\":4}] ,\"StatusCode\":1}"`

Comment: @Carl Can you also please tell me how to remove the square brackets on this?

Comment: The square brackets denotes a list of objects, this is the JSON syntax. if you want a flat object, create a class with multiple properties e.g. callinfoId1, callinfoId2 etc and serialise that. but this could be nasty if you don't know how many values you could get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using a `dictionary`:

```
[BasicAuthentication]
[Route("getactivecallinfoid")]
[HttpPost, ActionName("getactivecallinfoid")]
public System.Web.Http.Results.JsonResult<String> GetACII(String u_id)
        {
            using (EMSMVCEntities entities = new EMSMVCEntities())
            {
                String jsonResult = null;
                String jsonResult_log = null;

                entities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
                   
                var query_pre = entities.Database.SqlQuery<get_active_call_info_id_Result>("exec [dbo].[get_active_call_info_id] @user_id", new SqlParameter("user_id", u_id))
                    .ToList();

                var query = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                int counter = 1;
                foreach (var item in query_pre)
                { 
                    query.Add("call_info_id_"+counter.ToString(), item.call_info_id.ToString());
                    counter += counter;
                };
                query.Add("StatusCode","1");
                bool isEmpty = !query.Any();
                if (isEmpty)
                {
                    error_message error_status = new error_message()
                    {
                        StatusCode = 0
                    };

                    jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error_status);
                }
                else
                {
                    jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query); // <-- using Newtonsoft.Json
                }

                return Json(jsonResult);
            }
        }
```